# How to switch radio buttons from true back to false in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok, so I am able to turn the Radio Buttons from false to true, but I can't figure out a way to turn the radio buttons back to false when you uncheck them.  I was wondering if anyone could help me.

```
const [long, setLong] = useState(false);
       
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log({name, long, short, both, entry, exit})
        };
    
<input type="radio" value='isLong' name='long' onCheck={(e) => setLong(!long)}/>isLong?
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `checked` prop

```
<input type="radio" value='isLong' name='long' checked={long} onChange={(e) => setLong(!long)}/>isLong?
```

Also `long` and `short` are reserved words. Consider using different names.

And if the next state depends on the current state consider using callback form of `setState` calls

```
onChange={() => setLong(isLong => !isLong)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `input` of type `checkbox` for this specific problem